# haystack, whoosh can not make startswith search

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am a newbie in django and sorry if question is so trivial. Can someone tell me what is the relation between get_queryset() and get_context_data() funtions.

I have a haystack serachview. I am trying to make "startswith" search work. When I look for a full word which is indexed, I can see that word is found both in get_queryset and inside object_list in context. But when I look for the first 3 letters of this word I can see get_queryset() finds it but my object_list inside context is empty. How this 2 funtions works and why I have different search results.

for example: in database I have name like ; "nametolookfor"
 when I search for "nametolookfor", everything is fine.
 but when I search for "name" get_queryset can find it but its not in context

My view:

```
class MainPageView(SearchView):
    """ View for main page """
    template_name = "index.html"
    form_class = PersonalSearchForm
    model = PersonalProfileModel


    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MainPageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print context
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        form_class = PersonalSearchForm
        # further filter queryset based on some set of criteria
        queryset = super(MainPageView, self).get_queryset()
        form = form_class(self.request.GET or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            qr = form.cleaned_data['q']
            print qr
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__startswith=qr)
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(name__startswith=qr)
            print queryset
        return queryset
```

form:

```
class PersonalSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(PersonalSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        return sqs
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are involving Haystack and Whoosh here at all. `__startswith` is a straight Django model query, and you are indeed calling it on the model manager.

Comment: when I change my MainPageView to inherit from TemplateView , get_queryset function is not being called. And I am using haystack for also autocomplete feature. Is it possible here to cancel inheriting from SearchView and have this view make queries?